# How to override the default init.tcl

Tags: shell, tcl

I'm working on a project where I want to make use of TCL as the command interpreter.
I have a working c library object which I can load from within the tcl shell but my problem is finding a way to automatically do this while starting a tclsh.

Essentially my ultimate goal is to be able to run a script and have it load my library and run some initial startup tcl code before dropping me back to the tclsh command prompt in interactive mode.

e.g.

```
tclsh -f myscript.tcl --then-switch-to-interactive
```

or

```
EXPORT TCLINIT=myscript.tcl 
tclsh
```

The basic goal is to avoid having to distribute tclsh but rather rely in local user installations of tcl. All I would like to distribute is my library, a startup script and a shell command to launch the tclsh with the library preloaded.

I've tried using the environment variables `TCLINIT` and `TCL_LIBRARY` but they seem to have no effect.

The only workable solutions I've found so far are to add "source myscript.tcl" to either the end of `/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.5.init.tcl` or `~/.tclshrc`

However both of these "solutions" are non perfect as they require modification of the default users workspace.

It strikes me that there must be a way to handle this in TCL, but my research so far hasn't yielded anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Tcl does not provide any ability to replace `init.tcl`; it's used to set up parts of the language before user *or library* code is supposed to run. The only time it gets adjusted is in packaging systems like `tclkit` (which does extra work in there to initialize the internal virtual filesystem).

I also don't advise relying on the user to edit their `~/.tclshrc`, as that's *theirs* and not yours. It's also never sourced when running non-interactively (well, not unless you add in code to actually read it).

Instead, I advise that you consider:

- Distributing/installing your library as a Tcl package, so code that wants it can just do:

  ```
  package require itsname
  ```

  Like that, code that wants it can just declare the fact and code that doesn't is unaffected.
- Distributing/installing your library with a script that acts as an interactive shell. The [`commandloop`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1968) command from the [TclX package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclx) may help here, but that Wiki page also has code for doing your own.

Answer (score 0):

In myscript.tcl:

```
package require Tclx
# Your script
commandloop; # Start interactive session
# other commands
```

The `commandloop` command will create an interactive command loop. At this point, if the user type `exit`, then the script will exit without executing the other commands that follows the `commandloop` line. On the other hand, if the user types Crtl+D or Ctrl+Z to exit the `commandloop`, the other commands will be executed.

Reference for `commandloop`: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1968

#### Custom Prompt

If you don't like the default prompt, create a `proc` to return a custom prompt and pass it to `commandloop`:

```
proc customPrompt {} { return "tcl> " }
commandloop -prompt1 customPrompt
```